# team foundation server version control alert

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a VS2015-C# project solution written by someone else. I want to open it on another PC but the alert "Team foundation server version control " shows up every time and the files does not show up in the solution explorer window. Actually the project is not available and accessible in Visual studio. The solution is a win 8 app. Is it possible to open the solution on another PC without connection to the tfs server?

Comment: You can remove the version control by editing the project in a text editor, however you should still be able to open the project without doing so. Are you sure you have the windows 8 dev tools installed?

Comment: @bonyjoe no I have not installed anything regarding the win 8 apps! what should I install? and I am trying to open it on Win10. is that ok?

Comment: Yeah that should be fine, if you right click the project it should have a action like "install missing features". If not try reloading it and it should say that you are missing features and allow you to trigger an install.

Comment: @bonyjoe its not possible to install the features. I got error.

Comment: I can't help you there. I installed them the other day on my Win10 machine and I am able to open Win8 app projects now.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the win 8.1 app on my Win 10 PC the problem was solved.